# Populate textbox in a window using another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with two windows. One window contains textboxes while the other window is the keyboard. My problem now is that when I click on my Keyboard window I encounter error. I cannot type on the textbox I clicked on the other window. Here is my code.

When I click one textbox from window I, I trigger this Mouse event.

```
private void TextBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.Focus();      
}
```

I used sender as TextBox because my textboxes are programmatically added to my window. I used it to get the name of the textbox.

And here is my code when I click a button from my Keyboard window.

Let used button 1:

```
private void button_numeric_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Screen1 screen1 = new Screen1();
    screen1.textBox.Text += "1";
}
```

Screen1 is the window containing my textboxes.

How I possibly able to type text in my textbox using my created keyboard. I'm using C#. Anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `new Screen1();` you may need to use the actual instance of the screen, you may pass the same to the keyboard via constructor.

example

```
class Screen
{
    Keyboard keyboard;

    public Screen()
    {
        //pass the screen instance to the keyboard
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this);
    }

    //...

    private void TextBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.Focus();
        //open keyboard etc
        keyboard.Show();
    }
}

class Keyboard
{
    private Screen screenInstance;

    public Keyboard(Screen instance)
    {
        //store the instance in a member variable
        screenInstance = instance;
    }

    //...

    private void button_numeric_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //use the stored screen instance
        screenInstance.textBox.Text += "1";
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        //display logic etc
    }
}
```

above is just an example based on some assumptions, you may adjust/merge with your code as needed.

you may adjust the same to pass TextBox instance if you have multiple TextBoxes to be used

example

```
class Screen
{
    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();

    private void TextBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.Focus();
        //open keyboard etc
        keyboard.Show(textBox);
    }
}

class Keyboard
{
    private TextBox textBoxInstance;

    private void button_numeric_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //use the stored TextBox instance
        textBoxInstance.Text += "1";
    }

    public void Show(TextBox instance)
    {
        textBoxInstance = instance;
        //display logic etc
    }
}
```